# What happens when calling external an Fortran function with the wrong type of arguments?

Tags: floating-point, fortran, gfortran

If you have a standalone function in a file (not in a module) and you call it with a single-precision while it expects a double precision number:

main.f90 :

```
program main

  call test(1.0)
end program main
```

test.f90:

```
subroutine test(a)
    double precision :: a
    print *, "a", a
end subroutine
```

**How does the compiler "casts" from single to double precision in this case ?**
Using floating-point format, I would expect the bits to stay the same during the cast but additionnal zeroes to be appended. That is:

```
1 = 0 01111111 00000000000000000000000 in single-precision
```

and I would expect the final value to be 2^(-7):

```
0 01111111000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in double precision
```

Surprisingly, with gfortran 6.4.0, the final value is 5.2635442471208903E-315.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler does no casting.  What you have written is not Fortran.

In the main program the subroutine `test` has an implicit interface.  Essentially, the compiler knows nothing about this except that it is a subroutine.  You also tell it that it has a single (default) real argument.

It is your responsibility, not the compiler's, to provide the correct type and kind of argument when referencing the subroutine.  You failed there, so you do not have a compliant Fortran program.  The Fortran compiler owes you nothing.

What you will observe will depend on implementation details of the Fortran processor.  The subroutine expects a double precision argument and has no reason to believe it has anything else.  Whether there is copy-in/copy-out or some address passing<sup>1</sup>, the interpretation of memory will not match.  In the dummy argument, all but the bytes corresponding to the default real of the actual argument are "junk".

If you provide an explicit interface for the subroutine in the main program there will still be no casting, but the compiler will notice the mismatch.  Equally, some compilers (perhaps with certain compile flags) will do some checking even when an implicit interface is there.

---

<sup>1</sup> For details of the likely pass-by-reference, see the comment by user5713492.

Comment: Happy for you to add those details to my answer.  I also could do it, but if you copy in the attribution is much clearer.  Either way: thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -3):

I guess the compiler "casts" according to endianess. If you stak zeros on the left, you get:

```
0 00000000000 0000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000
```

Which is 5.2635442471208903E-315. You can check by forcing endianess at compile-time.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the extra bytes that will be read are all zeroes; it is supposed to be "junk" data from random memory location

Comment: There's no guarantee even that junk data is read. It's just wrong. Anything can happen, nasal daemons included.